# Auto close modal box after a certain amount of seconds

Tags: jquery, joomla, popup, modal-dialog

Hey guys I've searched here but couldn't find an answer about this.

I have a Joomla site and want to display a banner in the middle of the site using a modal box when the page loads. So far so good, I used this script I found here: http://www.thesimplexdesign.com/2011/03/update-for-subscription-pop-up.html and everything works like a charm.

My problem is when I add a code of my own that auto closes the modal box. This code works but the user then can't close the modal by himself. Could you please guide me on what to do so it works as it should (can auto close, but can be closed by the user also)?

My code is the one with the comment **//fade out after delay**

CODE:

```
var popupStatus = 0;
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
//this code will load popup with jQuery magic!
function loadPopup(){
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if(popupStatus==0){
        $j("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });
        $j("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        $j("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

//This code will disable popup when click on x!
function disablePopup(){
    //disables popup only if it is enabled
    if(popupStatus==1){
        $j("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        $j("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}   
//this code will center popup
function centerPopup(){
    //request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $j("#popupContact").height();
    var popupWidth = $j("#popupContact").width();
    //centering
    $j("#popupContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,
        "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
    });
    //only need force for IE6   
    $j("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });

}
//CONTROLLING EVENTS IN jQuery
$j(document).ready(function(){
    if ($j.cookie("anewsletter") != 1) {   
        //centering with css
        centerPopup();
        //load popup
        loadPopup();
        $j.cookie("anewsletter", "1", { expires: 1 });
    }
    //CLOSING POPUP
    //Click the x event!
    $j("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Click out event!
    $j("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    //Press Escape event!
    $j(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
            disablePopup();
        }
    });
    //fade out after delay
    $j("#backgroundPopup").delay(15000).fadeOut("slow");
    $j("#popupContact").delay(15000).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: have you tried using `setTimeout()` ?

Comment: no problem, should I post an answer or not? :D

Comment: If you gain points from it then by all means! I'll mark it answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

Try using `setTimeout()` instead of `delay()`